# Which join type is required for my query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a reputation points table for my members.

```
rep_id   |   mem_id   |   activity        |   points   |   article_id   |   comment_id
---------|------------|-------------------|------------|----------------|-----------------
1        |   99       |   Posted Comment  |   5        |   10343        |   239403
2        |   99       |   Introduction    |   50       |                |
3        |   99       |   Liked Comment   |   5        |   748          |   9302
```

As you can see, not all reputation points have an `article_id` or a `comment_id`, but when I list these records, if the record *does* have an `article_id`, I need to grab the `article_title` from the `blog_articles` table. The same with `comment_id`, if it's present, I need to grab the `comment` from the `blog_comments` table. If `article_id` or `comment_id` is missing, just print the original record as-is.

I would really appreciate if somebody could tell me which join to use for this query. I THINK, by looking at the documentation, it's a LEFT JOIN I need, which prints all records from the left, even though there are no matches in the right - but really unsure.

I'm not looking for any code, just tell me which join is recommended and I will code it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Left join is what you need, indeed. If the record does not have an `article_id` the value for `article_title` will be `NULL`. The same applies to `comment_id` / `comment`.

Answer (score 3):

You need an OUTER join. Outer joins come in the LEFT, RIGHT, and FULL varieties. You could write a query using either a LEFT or RIGHT outer join that would work, but probably a LEFT OUTER JOIN (commonly abbreviated just LEFT JOIN) is what you want.